# Optimizing django has_perm database query

Tags: mysql, django, postgresql, django-models

Model method has perm looks for all the permission from Group and Permission. which is a heavy query.How can i optimized query time or any other solution to check user permission.

Example:
    SELECT "auth_permission"."id", "auth_permission"."name", "auth_permission"."content_type_id", "auth_permission"."codename" FROM "auth_permission" INNER JOIN "auth_group_permissions" ON ( "auth_permission"."id" = "auth_group_permissions"."permission_id" ) INNER JOIN "auth_group" ON ( "auth_group_permissions"."group_id" = "auth_group"."id" ) INNER JOIN "auth_user_groups" ON ( "auth_group"."id" = "auth_user_groups"."group_id" ) INNER JOIN "django_content_type" ON ( "auth_permission"."content_type_id" = "django_content_type"."id" ) WHERE "auth_user_groups"."user_id" = 1235  ORDER BY "django_content_type"."app_label" ASC, "django_content_type"."model" ASC, "auth_permission"."codename" ASC

SELECT "auth_permission"."id", "auth_permission"."name", "auth_permission"."content_type_id", "auth_permission"."codename", "django_content_type"."id", "django_content_type"."name", "django_content_type"."app_label", "django_content_type"."model" FROM "auth_permission" INNER JOIN "auth_user_user_permissions" ON ( "auth_permission"."id" = "auth_user_user_permissions"."permission_id" ) INNER JOIN "django_content_type" ON ( "auth_permission"."content_type_id" = "django_content_type"."id" ) WHERE "auth_user_user_permissions"."user_id" = 1235  ORDER BY "django_content_type"."app_label" ASC, "django_content_type"."model" ASC, "auth_permission"."codename" ASC

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: its the query time which its takes to check permission of a user.

Comment: are you running with `DEBUG = True`?